# Construction of $\mu$ and $\mathfrak M$ in Riesz Representation Theorem (Rudin)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-explanation

Rudin defines

> For every open set $V$, $$\mu(V) = \sup\{\Lambda f: f\prec V\}\ \  \ldots \text{(1)}$$ where $f\prec V$ means that $f\in C_c(X)$, $0\le f\le 1$, $\text{supp}(f) \subset V$.

$\color{red}{\text{Question 1. }}$Then they go on to say, *it is clear that* if $V_1\subset V_2$, then $\mu(V_1) \le \mu(V_2)$ according to the above definition. Why is that? $$\mu(V_1) = \sup\{\Lambda f: f\prec V_1\}, \mu(V_2) = \sup\{\Lambda f: f\prec V_2\}$$
Thus far, we don't know that $\Lambda f = \int_x f d\mu$, since $\mu$ was constructed *just now*.

The author now concludes using the above definition of $\mu(V)$ for open sets, that

> $$\begin{equation}\mu(E) = \inf\{\mu(V): E\subset V, V\text{ is open}\}\end{equation} \ \  \ldots \text{(2)}$$ if $E$ is an open set, and it is consistent with (1) to define $\mu(E)$ by (2) for every $E\subset X$.

$\color{red}{\text{Question 2. }}$Where does this come from? I see it is consistent with the previous definition because of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2824233/construction-of-measure-in-riesz-repr-thm-rudin).

> Let $\mathfrak M_F$ be the class of all $E\subset X$ which satisfy $\mu(E) < \infty$ and $\mu(E) = \sup\{\mu(K): K\subset E, K\text{ is compact}\}$. Finally let $\mathfrak M$ be the class of all $E\subset X$ such that $E\cap K\in\mathfrak M_F$ for every compact $K$. It is evident that $\mu$ is monotone, i.e. $\mu(A) \le \mu(B)$ if $A\subset B$ - and that $\mu(E) = 0$ implies $E\in \mathfrak M_F$ and $E\in\mathfrak M$. Thus (e) holds, and so does (c), by definition.

$\color{red}{\text{Question 3. }}$Why is $\mu$ monotone? This is not obvious to me yet. Also, suppose $\mu(E) = 0$. Then, $\mu(E) < \infty$ - but why is $\mu(E) = \sup\{\mu(K): K\subset E, K\text{ is compact}\}$? Basically, how do we know that $E\in \mathfrak M_F$ and $E\in\mathfrak M$? If everything above holds, I do agree that (e) and (c) hold.

Thanks a lot! I have provided pictures the text below for context:

> [image]
> [image]
> [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

Question 1:

If $V_1$ and $V_2$ are open and $V_1\subset V_2$, then
$$
\{\Lambda f:f\in C_c(X),\, f\prec V_1\}\subset \{\Lambda f:f\in C_c(X),\, f\prec V_2\}
$$
for if $\operatorname{supp}(f)\subset V_1$, then $\operatorname{supp}\subset V_2$. The rest of this question follows from properties of the supremum of sets. So
\begin{align}
\widetilde{\mu}(V_1)\leq \widetilde{\mu}(V_2)
\end{align}

---

Question 2 is not difficult to check. To clarify, lets define
$$
\begin{align}
\widetilde{\mu}(V):&=\sup\{\Lambda f: f\in C_c(X),\, f\prec V\} \tag{1}\label{one}
\end{align}
$$
for $V$ open, and
$$
\begin{align}
\mu(E):&=\inf\{\widetilde{\mu}(E): V\,open, \, E\subset V\} \tag{2}\label{two}
\end{align}
$$
What Rudin claims is that $\mu(E)=\widetilde{\mu}(V)$ when $E$ is open. This is immediate consequence of definition \eqref{one} for open sets, for
$E\in\{V\,open, \, E\subset V\}$ when $E$ is open; moreover, when $E$ is open, the $\inf$ is in fact a $\min$.

---

Question 3:

Once that it has been established that $\mu$ extends the definition of $\widetilde{\mu}$ to any subset in $X$, i.e., $\mu=\widetilde{\mu}$ when restricted to open sets, let's use $\mu$ henceforth.

Also, notice that $\mu$ is monotone, for if $E_1\subset E_2$, the
$$
\{\mu(V):\, V\,open,\, E_2\subset V\}\subset \{\mu(V):\, V\,open,\, E_1\subset V\}
$$
and so, by the properties of $\inf$, $\mu(E_1)\leq\mu(E_2)$.

The rest is to restrict $\mu$  to  special classes of sets: $\mathfrak M_F$ and later on $\mathfrak M$. This is to produce a measure that is inner regular and outer regular (Rudin uses the Lebesgue-Carathéodory notion of measurability and first proves that $\mu$ is an outer measure, and that the sets in $\mathfrak M$ are measurable, and $\mathfrak M$ contains the Borel sets.)

---

Comment: Thanks Oliver! I understand things better now. Could you fix the MathJax error in Q2's answer? Also, what is the motivation behind defining $\widetilde{\mu}$? If in the end, I must define $\mu(E)$ by the second expression for all $E\in\mathfrak M$, why bother about $\widetilde{\mu}$ at all?

Comment: @epsilon-emperor: The motivation follows from the inner and outer regularities of the Lebesgue measure of the line. People in the Bourbaki school realized that the Urysohn lemma could be used to extend the results of Riesz on the real line to locally compact Hausdorff spaces. There is alternative construction of integration that seems to me more natural than the ways of Lebesgue-Caratheodory, that is the Daniell integral and its refinement by Stone.

Comment: Oh, I see! Would you have any references I could check out to learn more about the alternative construction you mention?

Comment: @epsilon-emperor: My suggestion is that you keep learning integration theory from Rudin, but to round your knowledge with Daniell's integral, my favorite book is integration theory: A functional approach by Klaus Bichteler. Klaus has a nice presentation of the Daniell-Stone integral in terms of seminorms on space of functions and built from there the space of integrable functions and also makes a connection with the standard Lebesgue-Carathepdory method.

Comment: Cool, will check that out. Thanks so much @Oliver!